# I'm having trouble getting into safe mode trouble on galaxy ace

Tags: data-recovery

I can't get into safe mode on my galaxy ace SM-S765C. I tried holding down power and menu buttons but it doesn't work.

Answer (score -1):

Well, what you can try is firstly make sure that you have switched your device completely off, next step would be turning the phone back on, pressing power button+and also hold the menu button, now continue holding the menu button until you see the Home Screen ! This will boot you onto the safe mode ! :)